# user name has already been taken

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

okay people, I hope someone can help me here. **first off I would like to say that I am not asking for code** just some help on my connection issue with a database I'm having.

I have all of my files for my website in the www directory of wamp server which I'm running windows seven. The www directory is the localhost which most of us know that already, I have my table.sql file in that directory as well with the php files for my website.

my problem is I loaded up the table.sql on phpmyadmin and tested the sql file and works how ever when I go to register it says " This username is already taken! " although there is nothing in the database... weird right?

I've been trying for days to get it to work correctly I have posted some code from my website to see if someone here can point out the mistake so that I can correct it.

NOTE: the website it self works fine, having issues trying to register and sign in.

one last question do I have to have the usr and password for mysql on the connect.php file or for the myphpadmin?

**here is the source code or markup from the main page. "demo.php"**

```
<?php

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';
// Those two files can be included only if INCLUDE_CHECK is defined


session_name('tzLogin');
// Starting the session

session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
// Making the cookie live for 2 weeks

session_start();

if($_SESSION['id'] && !isset($_COOKIE['tzRemember']) && !$_SESSION['rememberMe'])
{
    // If you are logged in, but you don't have the tzRemember cookie (browser restart)
    // and you have not checked the rememberMe checkbox:

    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    // Destroy the session
}


if(isset($_GET['logoff']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    header("Location: demo.php");
    exit;
}

if($_POST['submit']=='Login')
{
    // Checking whether the Login form has been submitted

    $err = array();
    // Will hold our errors


    if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
        $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

    if(!count($err))
    {
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $_POST['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['rememberMe'] = (int)$_POST['rememberMe'];

        // Escaping all input data

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));

        if($row['usr'])
        {
            // If everything is OK login

            $_SESSION['usr']=$row['usr'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $_POST['rememberMe'];

            // Store some data in the session

            setcookie('tzRemember',$_POST['rememberMe']);
        }
        else $err[]='Wrong username and/or password!';
    }

    if($err)
    $_SESSION['msg']['login-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    // Save the error messages in the session

    header("Location: demo.php");
    exit;
}
else if($_POST['submit']=='Register')
{
    // If the Register form has been submitted

    $err = array();

    if(strlen($_POST['username'])<4 || strlen($_POST['username'])>32)
    {
        $err[]='Your username must be between 3 and 32 characters!';
    }

    if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.]+/i',$_POST['username']))
    {
        $err[]='Your username contains invalid characters!';
    }

    if(!checkEmail($_POST['email']))
    {
        $err[]='Your email is not valid!';
    }

    if(!count($err))
    {
        // If there are no errors

        $pass = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].microtime().rand(1,100000)),0,6);
        // Generate a random password

        $_POST['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $_POST['username'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        // Escape the input data


        mysql_query("   INSERT INTO tz_members(usr,pass,email,regIP,dt)
                        VALUES(

                            '".$_POST['username']."',
                            '".md5($pass)."',
                            '".$_POST['email']."',
                            '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                            NOW()

                        )");

        if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)
        {
            send_mail(  'demo-test@tutorialzine.com',
                        $_POST['email'],
                        'Registration System Demo - Your New Password',
                        'Your password is: '.$pass);

            $_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']='We sent you an email with your new password!';
        }
        else $err[]='This username is already taken!';
    }

    if(count($err))
    {
        $_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'] = implode('<br />',$err);
    }   

    header("Location: demo.php");
    exit;
}

$script = '';

if($_SESSION['msg'])
{
    // The script below shows the sliding panel on page load

    $script = '
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){

            $("div#panel").show();
            $("#toggle a").toggle();
        });

    </script>';

}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome to AZ Barter</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login_panel/css/slide.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- PNG FIX for IE6 -->
    <!-- http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6 -->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="login_panel/js/pngfix/supersleight-min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="login_panel/js/slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php echo $script; ?>
</head>


<body>

<!-- Panel -->
<div id="toppanel">
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="left">
                <h1>Welcome to AZ Barter</h1>
                <h2>Register/login ====></h2>       
                <p class="grey"></p>

            </div>


            <?php

            if(!$_SESSION['id']):

            ?>

            <div class="left">
                <!-- Login Form -->
                <form class="clearfix" action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Member Login</h1>

                    <?php

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['login-err'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['login-err'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['login-err']);
                        }
                    ?>

                    <label class="grey" for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="password" name="password" id="password" size="23" />
                    <label><input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" /> &nbsp;Remember me</label>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="bt_login" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="left right">            
                <!-- Register Form -->
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Not a member yet? Sign Up!</h1>     

                    <?php

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="err">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-err'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-err']);
                        }

                        if($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'])
                        {
                            echo '<div class="success">'.$_SESSION['msg']['reg-success'].'</div>';
                            unset($_SESSION['msg']['reg-success']);
                        }
                    ?>

                    <label class="grey" for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" size="23" />
                    <label class="grey" for="email">Email:</label>
                    <input class="field" type="text" name="email" id="email" size="23" />
                    <label>A password will be e-mailed to you.</label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="bt_register" />
                </form>
            </div>

            <?php

            else:

            ?>

         <div class="left">

            <h1>Members panel</h1>

            <p>You can put member-only data here</p>
            <a href="registered.php">View a special member page</a>
            <p>- or -</p>
            <a href="?logoff">Log off</a>

            </div>

            <div class="left right">
            </div>

            <?php
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /login -->  

    <!-- The tab on top --> 
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="login">
            <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['usr'] ? $_SESSION['usr'] : 'Guest';?>!</li>
            <li class="sep">|</li>
            <li id="toggle">
                <a id="open" class="open" href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['id']?'Open Panel':'Log In | Register';?></a>
                <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#">Close Panel</a>         
            </li>
            <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul> 
    </div> <!-- / top -->

</div> <!--panel -->


<div id="main_container">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/az_barter.png" border="0" alt="" title="" /></div>       
    </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>                                                                         
                <li class="selected"><a href="index.php">home</a></li>             
            </ul>
        </div>

    <div class="center_content">

        <div class="center_left">
            <div class="welcome_box">
            <p class="welcome">
<span class="orange">Welcome to AZ BARTER !!! </span><br />
Here at AZ Barter we trade, buy, and sell anything from your ordinary house hold items to vehicles. I hope here at AZ Barter we have created a fun, secure and enjoyable way to purchase your favorite products. AZ Barter deals with trading, buying, and selling options via PAYPAL only.  
            </p>

            </div>



         <div class="features">   
            <div class="title">Latest News</div>
                <div class="news_box">
                    <div class="news_icon"></div>
                    <div class="news_content">
                   You must be logged on to view products buy/sell and or trade , we apologize for the inconvenience.  
                    </div>   
                </div>
                <div class="news_box">
                    <div class="news_icon"></div>
                    <div class="news_content">
                    Posting your ads here will always be free of charge. 
                    </div>   
                </div>       

         </div> 





        </div> 


        <div class="center_right">

        <div class="software_box"><img src="images/computer.jpg" alt="" title="" /></div>





        </div>  

        <div class="clear"></div> 

    </div>    


    <div id="footer">                                              
        <div class="left_footer"><a href="index.php">home</a><a href="policy.php">privacy policy</a><a href="contact.php">contact</a></div>

        </div>   

    </div>



</div>
<!-- end of main_container -->

</body>
</html>
```

**Here is the code for the connect.php file**

```
<?php

if(!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) die('You are not allowed to execute this file directly');


/* Database config */

$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'admin';
$db_pass        = 'Shadowman80';
$db_database    = 'table.sql'; 





/* End config */



$conn = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die('Unable to establish a DB connection');

mysql_select_db($db_database,$conn);
mysql_query("SET names UTF8");

?>
```

**here is the code for the table.sql file**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tz_members`
--

CREATE TABLE `tz_members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `usr` varchar(32) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `pass` varchar(32) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `email` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `regIP` varchar(15) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `dt` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `usr` (`usr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I'm running the latest version of wamp on my machine.

Comment: In database name you have give filename i think. Rather you should give name of the database_schema in db

Answer (score 1):

Your database connection is not correct. So every time condition

`if(mysql_affected_rows($link)==1)`

become false and it shows message what you can see.

```
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'admin';
$db_pass        = 'Shadowman80';
$db_database    = '<databaseName>'; //Here it might cause issue
```

Comment: I have tried all of those suggestions and then some others I Googled still same result... I do however appreciate the suggestions. I will continue to figure it out feel free to post more info thanks :D

Comment: yeah i figured it out thanks though i appreciate the responses you guys gave me a lot of ideas what i did was reinstalled and reconfigured phpmyadmin and mysql viola it worked had credentials wrong thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I can see that your using the sql file as your database written on this line:

> $db_host        = 'localhost';
>     $db_user        = 'admin';
>     $db_pass        = 'Shadowman80';
>     $db_database    = 'table.sql';

try using the $db_database as a real time database connection like using mysql_select_db("db_name") as your mean to the connection

Answer (score 0):

yeah i figured it out thanks though i appreciate the responses you guys gave me a lot of ideas what i did was reinstalled and reconfigured phpmyadmin and mysql viola it worked had credentials wrong thanks :D